# Best way to query nested relationships in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, eloquent

I have built an application with Laravel where I end up having rather deep-nested relationships, that I sometimes need to query. Database is MySQL.

For instance, I want to retrieve all *Users* who are allowed to read a *Book*. My data is structured as follows:

- A *User* belongs to 0-n *UserGroups* through a *UserMembership*
- A *UserGroup* has 0-n *Rights*
- A *Right* relates to 1 *Book* and describes what action can be performed

After looking and browsing, I found that some people were recommending the following way to address nested relationships:

```
// class Book extends Model
public function readers() {
    $bookId= $this->id;
    return User::whereHas('memberships', function($m) use($bookId) {
        $m->whereHas('group', function($g) use($bookId) {
            $g->whereHas('rights', function($r) use($bookId) {
                $r->where('resource_id', $bookId)->where('action', 'read');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I like that the code makes a lot of sense, but the performance is terrible.. Execution time is **430ms** on average for `Book::find(967)->readers()->get()`

I re-wrote the function as follows:

```
public function readersNew() {
    $bookId= $this->id;
    $g = Right::where('resource_id', $bookId)->where('action', 'read')->pluck('group_id');
    $uIds = UserMembership::whereIn('group_id', $g)->pluck('user_id');
    return User::whereIn('id', $uIds);
}
```

With this code I achieve an average exec time of **4ms** which is obviously much better. But this also looks much less "methodical" in terms of writing nested requests.

I would really like to understand :

- why *readers()->get()* is so much slower than *readersNew()->get()*
- what the best way is to write such requests

Comment: Since the "best way" is really determined by the generated SQL, please show us that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, good job for improving the performance without even knowing why is it happening :)

#### Q1: why readers()->get() is so much slower than readersNew()->get()

Your `readers()->get()` function traverse in the hierarchy up to down which is why it makes more sense but its slower. It is same as running 3 foreach nested loops, it first returns all users which has membership and then iterate for each user and finds all the groups its belongs and then iterates each group and find the rights for each and then iterates each rights and gets the desired entry by matching resource_id and action.

whereas your `readersNew()->get()` traverse in the hierarchy down to up, that is why its faster. It first extracts the target group based upon the matched right and then extracts the membership, user associated with that group, hence faster.

#### Q2 what the best way is to write such requests

The approach `readersNew()->get()` is the best, you could just change your writing conventions to make more sense if you like:

```
public function readersNew() {
    $bookId= $this->id;
    $targetGroup = Right::where(['resource_id' => $bookId, 'action' => 'read'])->pluck('group_id');
    $associatedUserIds = UserMembership::whereIn('group_id', $g)->pluck('user_id');
    return User::whereIn('id', $associatedUserIds);
}
```

*I hope it helps*